# Correct setup for a Bayesian gamma model

Tags: gamma-distribution, quality-control

I am interested in understanding how center volume affects a quality metric in a [healthcare application](https://www.srtr.org/about-the-data/technical-methods-for-the-program-specific-reports/). Each program's performance is reported as an observed/expected (O/E) ratio where the expected count of outcomes is estimated from a multivariable model. The O/E ratio is calculated by (O+2)/(E+2). The distribution of this ratio is calculated using a Bayesian method where the prior is a gamma distribution with shape=2 and rate=2 (mean=1, variance 0.5), and the posterior distribution is a gamma distribution with shape = 2 + observed count and rate = 2 + expected count.

Does this suggest that for a center with 50 observed events and 40 expected events that:

```r
HR = (2+50)/(2+40)
HRprior = gamma(2,2)
HRposterior = gamma(52, 42)
```

If not, please correct me.

Some R code for thinking with:

```r
# Ratios
  hr <- 50/40
  hr.prior <- 2/2
  hr.posterior <- (2+50)/(2+40)

# Distributions
  hr.prior.dist <- rgamma(10000, 2, 2)
  mean(hr.prior.dist) #1.002
  var(hr.prior.dist)  #0.512
  
  hr.post.dist <- rgamma(10000, 2+50, 2+40)
  mean(hr.post.dist)
  var(hr.post.dist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. To confirm, I downloaded the 2021—2022 data for Table B6: *Rates of patient mortality after listing*. (The healthcare application is organ transplantation.) The expected & observed number of deaths for adult candidates are denoted by `sfl_ad_exp_c` & `sfl_ad_obs_c`, respectively.

Let's do the calculations for the hazard ratio (HR) using the STRT.org Bayesian methodology: The prior on HR is Gamma (with parameters `shape` and `rate`), the likelihood of the data (number of deaths) is Poisson. The Gamma is the conjugate prior for the Poisson, so the posterior distribution of the hazard ratio is Gamma as well.

```r
# prior: hr ~ gamma(prior.shape, prior.rate)
prior.shape <- 2
prior.rate <- 2

# likelihood: observed deaths ~ poisson(expected deaths)
# sfl_ad_obs_c ~ poisson(sfl_ad_exp_c)

# posterior: hr ~ gamma(posterior.shape, posterior.rate)
posterior.shape <- sfl_ad_obs_c + 2
posterior.rate <- sfl_ad_exp_c + 2
```

The 95% credible interval for HR is calculated as $[q_{0.025}, q_{0.975}]$ where $q_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-quantile of the Gamma distribution.

```r
qgamma(c(0.025, 0.975), shape = posterior.shape, rate = posterior.rate)
```

We can check that, for each transplant center/program, this gives the reported lower & upper bounds `sfl_ad_hr_lb_c` & `sfl_ad_hr_ub_c`. And the posterior mean `sfl_ad_hr_c` is calculated as `posterior.shape / posterior.rate`.

Comment: I found this question interesting as last year I read "[Voices in the Code: A Story about People, Their Values, and the Algorithm They Made](https://muse.jhu.edu/book/101537)" by David Robinson. It's about the organ donation program in the US. The book raises many challenging questions. And the stories of the people who made the program happen and evolve are incredible.